# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SearchQuery'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have update tslint to eslint, and now for this class i have error like this

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SearchQuery'.**

This is class I am talking about

```
export abstract class SearchQuery {
    transformQueryIntoText(): QueryValue[] {
        const queryValues: QueryValue[] = [];
        for (const key of Object.keys(this)) {
            if (this[key]) {
                queryValues.push({
                    name: key,
                    value: this[key].toString()
                });
            }
        }
        return queryValues;
    }
}
```

I dont know even how to start?

Comment: My guess is this[key] is problematic? Are you picking component scoped variables with that? If so, that is not an ideal way. Missing further context here to determine exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will affect the intended usage of your `SearchQuery` class, but one approach could be to "tell" TSC that your base class will have dynamic properties. Something like this:

```
interface QueryValue {
  value: string;
  name: string;
}

export abstract class SearchQuery {
  [key: string]: unknown; // <-- This line
  transformQueryIntoText(): QueryValue[] {
    const queryValues: QueryValue[] = [];
    for (const key of Object.keys(this)) {
      if (this[key]) {
        queryValues.push({
          name: key,
          value: this[key].toString()
        });
      }
    }
    return queryValues;
  }
}
```

Now should be safe to call `this[key]`